# Hive url parsing

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a question about parsing url using hive 
For example, I have a table of urls,

1. http://xxxx.com&key1 = 1&key2 = 2&key4 = 4
2. http://xxxx.com&key1 = 1&key2 = 2&key3 = 3 &key 4 = 4
3. http://xxxx.com&key1 = 1&key5 = 5
4. http://.....
5. http://....

I need a output like this

```
key1  key2  key3  key4
 1     2    null   4
 1     2      3    4
 1    null  null   5
```

....
...

I don't know the number of possible keys.
How can I get this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be `http://xxxx.com? ...` (`?` after the host)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the parse_url udf in HIVE along with the LATERAL VIEW explode keyword to convert each key/value pair into a new row : 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView

This post might be helpful as well: 
[How to parse url query string in Hive to multiple key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143562/how-to-parse-url-query-string-in-hive-to-multiple-key-value-pairs)